# setValue() in IE7 throws an error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am having to support IE7 and the following line is throwing an error in the console:

```
document.getElementById("statusFilter").setValue("0");
```

The error I am getting is:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'setValue'".

Is there an alternative for IE7? This works absolutely fine in IE8/9, FF and Chrome.

Comment: (@epascarello has provided an answer) But I'm curious... as far as I know `setValue` is not a valid method in _any_ browser?! What type of element is "statusFilter"?

Comment: statuFilter is a select object. The developer before me had included some external libraries and setValue essentially replaced .value=

Comment: In that case, it looks like `setValue()` would have been provided by the external library. Having since tested this, `setValue()` does not work in any browser by default. It's possible that setValue() provided some additional validation...?

Comment: Just to add... old browsers did not support the `value` property (and apparently [Konqueror does not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7242613/369434)) so a `setValue()` method might have been required (in the past) for cross browser support.

Comment: Yes, setValue() was definitely added by an external browser. The value property certainly works fine for IE7+ which is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("statusFilter").value = "0";
```